# Is there a way to convert C# code to JSON

Tags: c#, json, .net

is there a way to convert C# code to any block representation and back?
Something like this:

`int foo(int a){return a+1;}`

to

`{function:{name:"foo", return:"int", args:[{type:"int", name:"a"}], operations:[{type:"return", operations:[{type:"add", args:[{type:"vairable", value:"a"},{type:"const", value: 1}]}]}]}}`

Does not have to be JSON, but I need it to be split to smallest parts.

UPDATE:

Lets say I generate a function that fills a structure based on a data from database:

```
public Person GetPerson(int id)
{
  try {    // <-- entire block added by user
    using (var query = db.GetPerson(id))
    {
      return new Person(){
        /*0*/name = query['name'],    // /*#*/ is my mark of generated line
        /*1*/age = query['age']
      };
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Assume that a user changed the line:
`/*1*/age = query['age']`
to `/*1*/age = 10 - query['age']` for some reason.
Now the database column age is changed to years.
The new line should be `/*1*/years = 10 - query['years']`. The problem is that I need to keep the `10 -` entered by the user.

If I had this code is JSON (or any graph) I could find the part that needs to be changed and only affect the nodes I genereated before keeping the excess.

This exmaple is trivial, but it can get complicated very quickly. Especially with quotes and brackets. This is the only approach I can see to work right now. Just hoped that tools for it already exists.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why? It's dangerous enough to load and execute C# code from an external source, but now you want to break it apart? C# syntax can get very complex, the JSON schema would need to match that, and that doesn't seem feasible.

Comment: I am working on a system that generates and updates code for a specific purpose. It also allows a user to make changes. As for now this is the best way I can see to track changes from both sources.

Comment: seems like you are wanting expression trees

Comment: An IDE allows you to make code changes easily and a version control tool like git allows you to track changes. Why do those tools not fulfill your requirement?

Comment: Because some of the changes are made by the bot. I am not sure if with it I can find a place where the change are to be made (I can if code was not altered by user, if it was then all bets are off), yet alone resolving conflicts.

Comment: Sounds like you need to describe what you're ultimately after. It's quite unclear what you're trying to gain from this and what kind of system you have. Having a "bot" commit something to a git repository can definitely be done.

Comment: @Xerillio the bot commiting code is not a problem. I have a system that generates code around database structure based on a cs file template. The system also is suppose to allow a user to tweak the code. The part that bot generates is the part based on database structure, which in course of development can change, so can the cs file template. These two last changes on their own do not pose a problem, because if I re-generate the code from scratch will be identical to the one that got all changes incrementally. However I still need to track all the tweaks that the user made, this is the problem

Comment: @Xerillio as for now the best chance I can see of achiving this is to break down the file generated as last and find the tweaks by their relations to the rest of the code.

Comment: Perhaps I'm just clueless, but that doesn't seem to explain why it doesn't work to simply commit it to git. I don't see how this code->JSON conversion would be useful. Perhaps it's easier to understand if you update your question with some concrete examples and explain why typical tools are not enough for you.

Comment: I strongly feel like you are "asking the wrong question". I'd go back to the problem you want to solve and try to abstract it a bit more, then ask the question again. Converting code into json so that you can identify changed nodes honestly feels like a gigantic hack and/or implementation challenge that will be a nightmare to maintain. There must be a different solution to your problem that doesn't involve this.

Comment: @julealgon I would welcome any suggestion. This is the only way I can see.

Comment: If that example is really the essence of the problem, then there's a simple solution: Don't **ever** make manual changes to auto-generated code. Design your code in a way where you don't need to put manually written code together with auto-generated. Then you can regenerate the code however many times you want without keeping track of which manual changes were made.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to convert C# code to JSON

Sure. You can either make your json contain a string with your c# code and use runtime code generation to execute it, or encode dlls as base64 data and put it into your json. If you want to dig deeper you could probably extract the CIL code and make some custom JSON encoding of it. There are also expression trees, but I only think they allow encoding of *expressions*, not arbitrary code.

But in any case it is probably not a good idea to let the user customize code at that level. If you want to allow customization you should probably go for an actual plugin architecture. Or if you just want some customization of some simple mathematical expression, just store it as a string and write a simple parser to validate & evaluate it.

Comment: The idea is not to let user change the code at runtime, but to save the programmer time to copy-paste the same code multiple times with small differences (it happened to me several times), by generating those parts and still allow to make some exceptions to the rule. The generated code is to be normally compiled with the rest of the project. Like sharing a git project with a bot.
Expression trees may be the way, but this is the first time I hear of it, so who knows.

Comment: @Jamek It's possible something like [source generators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/) would be appropriate. But generally you would try to use the same source and use *configuration* for common changes. But this really sound like  XY-problem, you are asking about storing code in JSON, when your actual problem is something completely different.